# Direct proportional - basic concept

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Q : A stone is dropped from the top of a high tower. The distance it falls is proportional to the square of the time of fall. The stone falls 19.6 m after 2 seconds, how far does it fall after 3 seconds?

Formula : $y = kx^2$

[ref](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/directly-inversely-proportional.html)

My question is how to determine/decide which value is **x** and which **y**? Or is it completely based on experience that for different problems what value come what side?

Comment: I think your formula is wrong. It should be $y=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$, where $y$=distance travelled during free fall, $g$=acceleration due to gravity and $t$=time of fall.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to use proportional symbol without k. let me correct it.

Comment: So, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> $y$ is directly proportional to $x$

means that $y=kx$ for some $k$.

Here, $d$ is the distance fallen is directly proportional to the square of the time of the fall: $t^2$.  To make the sentence the same as the definition, we can say

> $d$ is directly proportional to $t^2$

which means $d = k t^2$ for some $k$.  You have one example given: $19.6 = k \cdot 2^2$.  Once you've found $k$, you will have a formula for $d$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: Actually I want to know how you came to know y is distance and x is time? If I remove "The distance it falls is proportional to the square of the time of fall." from the original question, then I can say is distance is increased if time is increased and similarly time will increase if distance is increased.

Comment: That is the meaning of the sentence "The distance it falls is proportional to the square of the time of fall".  Read it symbolically as "$d$ is proportional to $t^2$".  That sentence means $d = kt^2$.

Comment: @AmitGupta Expanding here $k=\frac{1}{2}g$, where $k$ is a constant. It is important to note that increase may not be linear, as shown in this case. Had it been of the form $y=kx$, then $k$ would no longer be a constant.